# Como relacionar estas tabelas, retornando valores especificos?

Tags: sql, firebird, join

[Firebird] sgbd - IBExpert

Preciso saber como eu faço para relacionar estas duas tabelas (comentário abaixo), da forma que eu consiga os seguintes resultados:

---

TABELA:CONTARECEBER

- **DTDOCUMENTO** (data que entrou no sistema)
- **DTVENCIMENTO** (data que o documento irá vencer)
- **DTCANCELAMENTO** (data de cancelamento do documento)
- **STCANCELADA** (status de cancelado do documento)
- **CODCONTARECEBER** (código do documento)

---

TABELA: CONTARECEBERQUITACAO

- **CODCONTARECEBERQUITACAO** (código da quitação do documento, se houver)
- **DTQUITACAO** (Data que o documento foi quitado, se houver)

---

Estes, são os que eu preciso exibir, eles estão em duas tabelas, tentei usar o LEFT JOIN no meu comando, mas não está dando certo, pensei que poderia estar fazendo algo errado também.

```
select 
    contareceber.dtdocumento,
    contareceber.dtvencimento,
    contareceber.dtcancelamento,
    contareceber.stcancelada,
    contareceber.codcontareceber,
    contareceber.codorganizacao,
    contareceberquitacao.dtquitacao,
    contareceberquitacao.codcontareceberquitacao
from contareceber
   left join contareceberquitacao on (contareceber.codcontareceberquitacao = contareceberquitacao.codcontareceberquitacao)
where (contareceber.dtdocumento between '01.01.2015' and '31.12.2015') and (contareceber.codorganizacao = '001')
```

Comment: qual é o gerenciador: Oracle Database? MariaDB? SQL Server? outro?  // Como está declarada a coluna dtdocumento?

Comment: (1) falta vírgula após `contareceberquitacao.dtquitacao`, na oitava linha // (2) A junção deve ser `contareceber.codcontareceber = contareceberquitacao.codcontareceberquitacao`

Comment: o codcontareceber não é o mesmo que codcontareceberquitação, são ID's distintos.

Comment: Então, como estabelecer a relação entre as duas tabelas? É necessário que exista no mínimo uma coluna em comum. Isto é, na tabela CONTARECEBERQUITACAO qual é a coluna que contém o código do documento?

Comment: Obrigado! era justamente esse o problema, ele tem o campo igual, as duas tabelas tem o CODCONTARECEBERQUITACAO, mas na tabela CONTARECEBE está indo zerado, agora sei que o problema é na hora de gravar os campos... como não está preenchido ele não encontra...

OBRIGADO de todo jeito !